# RaphaelJS - I need help understanding a transform

Tags: raphael, transform, vector-graphics

I have a question about the following demo - http://raphaeljs.com/hand.html.

Here is code from the sample...

```
var r = Raphael("holder", 640, 480), angle = 0;
while (angle < 360) {
    var color = Raphael.getColor();
    (function(t, c) {
        r.circle(320, 450, 20).attr({
            stroke : c,
            fill : c,
            transform : t,
            "fill-opacity" : .4
        }).click(function() {
            s.animate({
                transform : t,
                stroke : c
            }, 2000, "bounce");
        }).mouseover(function() {
            this.animate({
                "fill-opacity" : .75
            }, 500);
        }).mouseout(function() {
            this.animate({
                "fill-opacity" : .4
            }, 500);
        });
    })("r" + angle + " 320 240", color);
    angle += 30;
}
Raphael.getColor.reset();
var s = r.set();
s.push(r.path("M320,240c-50,100,50,110,0,190").attr({
    fill : "none",
    "stroke-width" : 2
}));
s.push(r.circle(320, 450, 20).attr({
    fill : "none",
    "stroke-width" : 2
}));
s.push(r.circle(320, 240, 5).attr({
    fill : "none",
    "stroke-width" : 10
}));
s.attr({
    stroke : Raphael.getColor()
});
```

The question I have is about the following line of code...

```
("r" + angle + " 320 240", color);
```

In the anonymous function the circle is initially drawn at 320, 450 with a radius of 20.   Then a transform is applied,   for example ("r30 320 240") when the angle is 30.

How does this transform work?  The way I read this transform is to rotate the circle 30 degrees around 320,450 , then move 320 horizontally (to the right) and 240 vertically down.

But i'm obviously reading this transform wrong because this is not what is happening.

What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transform `"r30 320 240"` **sets** the rotation of the object about the point (320,240) by 30 degrees. **It does not add to the rotation.** It overrides any previous transformations.

If you look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jZyyy/1/

You can see that I am setting the rotation of the circle about the point (0,0). If you consider the point (0,0) to be the centre of a clock, then the circle begins at 3 o'clock. If I use the transform `"r90 0 0"` the circle will be rotated from 3 o'clock to 6 o'clock. If I then later set the transform to be `"r30 0 0"` the circle will be at 4 o'clock, rotated 30 degrees from the original 3 o'clock position about the point (0,0).

Comment: Excellent, thanks Matt, that makes sense.   I appreciate your example it helped clear things up.

Draw the circle at a specific point,  then rotate it around another point.   Thanks again!   I will try to up-vote but not sure I have enough reputation yet.